# continued fraction of the roots of $x^2 - \frac{53793390359}{1088391168}x + \frac{823543}{12230590464} = 0$

Tags: quadratics, continued-fractions

I would like to find the continued fraction expansion of the roots of:

$$x^2 - \frac{53793390359}{1088391168}x + \frac{823543}{12230590464} = 0$$

Eq 1.6 from [[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03178)]

What makes this problem so difficult is obtaining numerical accuracy.   However, we have some starting points:

- since this is a quadratic the digits are ultimately periodic
- the continued fraction of the middle coefficient is $$ [49, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 1, 454, 3, 1, 4]$$
- the constant term is of order $10^{-6}$.

Since this is a quadratic, I am hoping an exact answer is possible.  Although the number $454$ may already rule out the possibility of a "[small divisors](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/resonancesmall.pdf)" explanation of the equation here.

---

**Work**  I have no idea what to do here.  My first guess is to approximate this equation as:

$$ x^2 - 49x + 0 = x(x-49) = 0 $$

so the roots are $x  = 0, 49$.  If I wanted to get more accuracy I could try dividing by $x$ and hoping for the best:

\begin{eqnarray} x &=& \underbrace{\frac{53793390359}{1088391168}}_A + \underbrace{\frac{823543}{12230590464}}_{1/B}\frac{1}{x} \\\\
&=& A + \frac{1}{B\, x} = A + \frac{1}{AB + \frac{1}{x}}\end{eqnarray}

The first two digits are... $x = [\lfloor A \rfloor, \lfloor AB \rfloor,...] = [49,734015,... ]$ so $x = \mathbf{49} $ is a really good guess!

Comment: what problems are you facing? did you tried to use a calculator?

Comment: What's keeping you from analytically computing the roots and obtaining a cfe for something of the form $p \pm \sqrt q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Have you tried the [VAS algorithm?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent%27s_theorem#Vincent.E2.80.93Akritas.E2.80.93Strzebo.C5.84ski_.28VAS.2C_2005.29)

Comment: @AlexR :D similiar.

Comment: Use the VAS algorithm, I'm getting that for the smaller root, you have an expansion of $[0;734012,....]$.  I'll try to get back to you with the full solution.

Comment: @MichaelBurr No I have not! *Even though Vincent's theorem is the basis of the fastest method for the isolation of the real roots of polynomials, **it was almost totally forgotten**, having been overshadowed by Sturm's theorem*

Comment: It is difficult to say that this is not possible but with 100,000 terms, it does not finish.

Comment: john, your final + sign is incorrect. It should be a - sign in the quadratic polynomial. Check the arXiv piece!!!

Answer (score 2):

illustration only:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior: ./indefCycle 101 -473 -137

  0  form            101        -473        -137  delta      0
  1  form           -137         473         101


           0          -1
           1           0

To Return  
           0           1
          -1           0

0  form   -137 473 101   delta  4
1  form   101 335 -413   delta  -1
2  form   -413 491 23   delta  22
3  form   23 521 -83   delta  -6
4  form   -83 475 161   delta  3
5  form   161 491 -59   delta  -8
6  form   -59 453 313   delta  1
7  form   313 173 -199   delta  -1
8  form   -199 225 287   delta  1
9  form   287 349 -137   delta  -3
10  form   -137 473 101


  form   -137 x^2  + 473 x y  101 y^2
```

Answer (score 1):

I computed the continued fraction out many terms, but didn't see a pattern.

Here's the Maple code that I used (following the VAS algorithm) to generate the continued fraction for the root near 49:

```
f := x^2-(53793390359/1088391168)*x+823543/12230590464; 
r := [evalf(solve(f = 0))]; 
m := floor(max(r)); 
cf := [m]; 
f := simplify((1+x)^2*subs(x = 1/(1+x)+49, f)); 
for a to 100 do 
    r := evalf(solve(f = 0)); 
    m := floor(max(r)); 
    cf := [op(cf), 1+m]; 
    f := simplify((1+x)^2*subs(x = 1/(1+x)+m, f)) 
end do
```

Here are the first 101 terms of the continued fraction:

For the smaller root:
$$[0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 17, 1, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 14, 35, 1, 1, 247, 1, 1, 4, 2, 15, 1, 1, 1, 16, 42, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 16, 3, 17, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 11, 1, 5, 1, 71, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 61, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 62, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 45, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 47, 1, 27, 1]$$

For the larger root:
$$[49, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 17, 1, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 14, 35, 1, 1, 247, 1, 1, 4, 2, 15, 1, 1, 1, 16, 42, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 16, 3, 17, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 11, 1, 5, 1, 71, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 61, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 62, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 45, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 47, 1, 27, 1]$$

By the way, the continued fraction expansion does not repeat before the 10,000th term.

Comment: There is an algorithm due to Gauss and Lagrange which does the full job with no need for decimal accuracy and none for "cycle detection" either. I have answered on MSE with that many times, also short description at  http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/   Favorite book on this is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. I copied the relevant chapter as a pdf if you would like to see that.

Comment: Oh, also, if you are not solving a Pell type equation, it is not necessary to keep any cumulative product of the little 2 by 2 transition matrices, so storage use is also small in that case. I have this program, it would suffice if I added in GMP oversize for the coefficients $a,b,c$ of the initial form $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2. $

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the reference!  What you have sounds very interesting.  If you're willing to share, I'd be happy to receive the program, you can Google for my contact.

Comment: Something is off; just with my calculator, I get the larger root as 49.42468611 , beginning SCF as $$49; 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 52,$$

Comment: did again, but with gp-pari, the 49 one does start out 49,2,2

Comment: @WillJagy I'll check the calculation again, I was doing a quick calculation in Maple.

Comment: @WillJagy I've edited my post and included the code.  I forgot to add 1 to the lower bounds to get the continued fraction.  I should have noticed the error because I shouldn't have had $0$'s in the continued fraction expansion.  I also plugged in your continued fraction expansion into the polynomial and your root might be a little off - I added/subtracted 1 from the last term and there was no sign change.

Comment: I think the number is about 49.42468610861698234697514403, could you please give a decimal version of yours? This is from the integer version on page numbered 22 (pdf page 23)

Comment: I see. John mistyped it from the beginning, as far as a $\pm$ sign, from the arXiv pdf it should be $$x^2 - \frac{53793390359}{1088391168}x - \frac{823543}{12230590464}$$

Comment: Alright, could you please do this over with the final + sign in your polynomial in your program changed to a - ?

Comment: I added the relevant page to my (second) answer, now one may see both versions in the original arXiv article.

Comment: @WillJagy I re-ran it and I agree with your calculation.  [49, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 52, 23, 2, 2, 25, 3, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 10, 2, 35, 1, 2, 197, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 44, 1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 15, 1, 738, 4, 108, 2, 31, 1, 1, 20, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11]

Comment: Michael, thank you. All sorts of problems when the  question is poorly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Revised my Gauss-Lagrange method program to just print out a form every 10,000,000 steps unless something good happens. Also switched to the form with integer coefficients on page 22 or 23 of the manuscript, which is already "reduced."

[image]

[image]

Anyway, the conclusion is that the continued fraction cycle is of length greater than $4 \cdot 10^9$ and we may never know how long it is. I stopped execution this morning because my monitor would not come on, had to shut off the computer and restart to see anything on the screen.

Highlights include:

```
2,767,313,342  new min   form   8751 440675478108752 -156710092210752   delta  -2
```

because we would always like to know the "minimum," the integer of smallest absolute value represented by the original form.

```
gp-pari

? f =     600362847  +   440675453820928 * x      -8916100448256 * x^2
%1 = -8916100448256*x^2 + 440675453820928*x + 600362847
? 
? polroots(f) 
%2 = [-1.362369574356248045442331538 E-6 + 0.E-28*I, 
      49.42468610861698234697514403 + 0.E-28*I]~
? 
? 
? 
? x =  49.42468610861698234697514403
%3 = 49.42468610861698234697514403
? 
? contfrac(x)
%4 = [49, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 52, 23, 2, 2, 25, 3, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 10, 2, 37]

First disagreement with my output below is the final "digit" above, it gives 37 instead of my 35



  0  form              600362847     440675453820928      -8916100448256


0  form   600362847 440675453820928 -8916100448256   delta  -49
1  form   -8916100448256 433102390108160 185540661325663   delta  2
2  form   185540661325663 309060255194492 -132958235361924   delta  -2
3  form   -132958235361924 222772686253204 271828230266951   delta  1
4  form   271828230266951 320883774280698 -83902691348177   delta  -4
5  form   -83902691348177 350337756504718 212920265818911   delta  1
6  form   212920265818911 75502775133104 -221320182033984   delta  -1
7  form   -221320182033984 367137588934864 67102858918031   delta  6
8  form   67102858918031 438096718081508 -8442794594052   delta  -52
9  form   -8442794594052 439953919699900 18815616839839   delta  23
10  form   18815616839839 425564454932694 -173921639416921   delta  -2
11  form   -173921639416921 270122102734990 174257969037543   delta  2
12  form   174257969037543 426909773415182 -17133968736729   delta  -25
13  form   -17133968736729 429788663421268 138271843961468   delta  3
14  form   138271843961468 399842400347540 -62053363347321   delta  -6
15  form   -62053363347321 344797959820312 303405165543152   delta  1
16  form   303405165543152 262012371265992 -103446157624481   delta  -3
17  form   -103446157624481 358664574480894 158426860720799   delta  2
18  form   158426860720799 275042868402302 -187067863703073   delta  -1
19  form   -187067863703073 99092859003844 246401865420028   delta  1
20  form   246401865420028 393710871836212 -39758857286889   delta  -10
21  form   -39758857286889 401466273901568 207624855093248   delta  2
22  form   207624855093248 429033146471424 -12191984717033   delta  -35
23  form   -12191984717033 424405783720886 288603703227663   delta  1
24  form   288603703227663 152801622734440 -147994065210256   delta  -2
25  form   -147994065210256 439174638106584 2230687855519   delta  197
26  form   2230687855519 439716376967902 -94632787370433   delta  -4
27  form   -94632787370433 317345921995562 246971597800199   delta  1
28  form   246971597800199 176597273604836 -165007111565796   delta  -1
29  form   -165007111565796 153416949526756 258561759839239   delta  1
30  form   258561759839239 363706570151722 -59862301253313   delta  -6
31  form   -59862301253313 354641044888034 285758335630303   delta  1
32  form   285758335630303 216875626372572 -128745010511044   delta  -2
33  form   -128745010511044 298104415671604 204529546331271   delta  1
34  form   204529546331271 110954676990938 -222319879851377   delta  -1
35  form   -222319879851377 333685082711816 93164343470832   delta  4
36  form   93164343470832 411629665054840 -66430715165329   delta  -6
37  form   -66430715165329 385538916929108 171436587848028   delta  2
38  form   171436587848028 300207434463004 -151762197631433   delta  -2
39  form   -151762197631433 306841356062728 164802666248304   delta  2
40  form   164802666248304 352369308930488 -106234244763673   delta  -3
41  form   -106234244763673 285036159651550 265802390166711   delta  1
42  form   265802390166711 246568620681872 -125468014248512   delta  -2
43  form   -125468014248512 255303436312176 257067574536407   delta  1
44  form   257067574536407 258831712760638 -123703876024281   delta  -2
45  form   -123703876024281 235983791336486 279915495960559   delta  1
46  form   279915495960559 323847200584632 -79772171400208   delta  -4
47  form   -79772171400208 314330170617032 298949555895759   delta  1
48  form   298949555895759 283568941174486 -95152786121481   delta  -3
49  form   -95152786121481 287347775554400 293281304325888   delta  1
50  form   293281304325888 299214833097376 -89219257349993   delta  -4
51  form   -89219257349993 414539225702568 62632519115504   delta  6
52  form   62632519115504 337051003683480 -321683923407257   delta  -1
53  form   -321683923407257 306316843131034 77999599391727   delta  4
54  form   77999599391727 317679952002782 -298957705663761   delta  -1
55  form   -298957705663761 280235459324740 96721845730748   delta  3
56  form   96721845730748 300095615059748 -269167472061249   delta  -1
57  form   -269167472061249 238239329062750 127649988729247   delta  2
58  form   127649988729247 272360625854238 -235046175269761   delta  -1
59  form   -235046175269761 197731724685284 164964439313724   delta  1
60  form   164964439313724 132197153942164 -267813460641321   delta  -1
61  form   -267813460641321 403429767340478 29348132614567   delta  14
62  form   29348132614567 418317945867398 -163596210952881   delta  -2
63  form   -163596210952881 236066897944126 211599180537839   delta  1
64  form   211599180537839 187131463131552 -188063928359168   delta  -1
65  form   -188063928359168 188996393586784 210666715310223   delta  1
66  form   210666715310223 232337037033662 -166393606635729   delta  -2
67  form   -166393606635729 433237389509254 9766362834631   delta  44
68  form   9766362834631 426202539938274 -321160297197289   delta  -1
69  form   -321160297197289 216118054456304 114808605575616   delta  2
70  form   114808605575616 243116367846160 -294161983807433   delta  -1
71  form   -294161983807433 345207599768706 63762989614343   delta  6
72  form   63762989614343 419948275603410 -69939956303321   delta  -6
73  form   -69939956303321 419331200036442 65614216315247   delta  6
74  form   65614216315247 368039395746522 -223815369173081   delta  -1
75  form   -223815369173081 79591342599640 209838242888688   delta  1
76  form   209838242888688 340085143177736 -93568468884033   delta  -4
77  form   -93568468884033 408462607894528 73083313455104   delta  5
78  form   73083313455104 322370526656512 -308798671979073   delta  -1
79  form   -308798671979073 295226817301634 86655168132543   delta  4
80  form   86655168132543 398014527758710 -103223251064921   delta  -4
81  form   -103223251064921 427771480760658 27141262128647   delta  15
82  form   27141262128647 386466383098752 -413011483529216   delta  -1
83  form   -413011483529216 439556583959680 596161698183   delta  738
84  form   596161698183 440378082558428 -109878500591204   delta  -4
85  form   -109878500591204 438649922171204 4052482472631   delta  108
86  form   4052482472631 436686291917092 -215914534313252   delta  -2
87  form   -215914534313252 426971845335916 13766929053807   delta  31
88  form   13766929053807 426577756000118 -222022919018121   delta  -1
89  form   -222022919018121 17468082036124 218321766035804   delta  1
90  form   218321766035804 419175450035484 -21169235018441   delta  -20
91  form   -21169235018441 427593950702156 134136759369084   delta  3
92  form   134136759369084 377226605512348 -96720252803153   delta  -4
93  form   -96720252803153 396535416912876 95519136568028   delta  4
94  form   95519136568028 367617675631348 -154555735366209   delta  -2
95  form   -154555735366209 250605265833488 212531546365888   delta  1
96  form   212531546365888 174457826898288 -192629454833809   delta  -1
97  form   -192629454833809 210801082769330 194359918430367   delta  1
98  form   194359918430367 177918754091404 -209070619172772   delta  -1
99  form   -209070619172772 240222484254140 163208053348999   delta  2
100  form   163208053348999 412609729141856 -36683374285056   delta  -11
856997  new min   form   -324518241 440675290597730 127318319881983   delta  3
1234567  form   -120259880879561 437934579168168 5006202739952   delta  87
1603662  new min   form   47941263 440675404060910 -340351986291681   delta  -1
6242824  new min   form   36554311 440675457475504 -124408157419584   delta  -3
11234567  form   -52474881577409 414756058952424 105632866180976   delta  4
12792061  new min   form   -16307076 440675473041644 68549780712519   delta  6
21234567  form   -240015607188241 382304678017922 50036340074127   delta  8
31234567  form   -265567577390864 197295639354488 146167417375503   delta  2
41234567  form   -20414066561769 427158800391196 143653840658396   delta  3
49187955  new min   form   -1792272 440675477774296 41882397784567   delta  10
51234567  form   -187925712932633 68397630764078 252116432286279   delta  1
61234567  form   -159444776862369 165763590482768 261402901309888   delta  1
71234567  form   -105287151336673 370051111202072 135954509603184   delta  2
81234567  form   -124710039158544 278061224543176 234297160850111   delta  1
91234567  form   -335500161204297 322508569971560 67200488803824   delta  5
101234567  form   -239743820434969 264851046547740 129355576224412   delta  2
111234567  form   -195977545812224 315181928303264 121002674936271   delta  3
121234567  form   -26285377265348 439635083519636 8710835128023   delta  50
131234567  form   -94246140738673 336951699664668 213956848717564   delta  1
141234567  form   -227334048333824 37811170457856 211984515532631   delta  1
151234567  form   -86921965484676 307004984099356 287449829835119   delta  1
160715429  new min   form   -262144 440675477662720 380130967686087   delta  1
161234567  form   -112679846742961 306073627889614 223007516933439   delta  1
171234567  form   -84939916820009 368174359264192 172599998880768   delta  2
181234567  form   -147950820924868 156344015420676 286837586964463   delta  1
191234567  form   -4905370733961 434512536978214 274889122206239   delta  1
201234567  form   -282926473630161 342860532007852 67722129021532   delta  5
211234567  form   -285592962687729 281144630126278 100801305535783   delta  3
221234567  form   -31799181669729 392309244933656 316740331322736   delta  1
231234567  form   -67733157525873 400556060071576 124568678711408   delta  3
241234567  form   -41768757345841 394670609600372 230016340989852   delta  1
251234567  form   -123905796234609 216099857513392 297596506936768   delta  1
261234567  form   -59245754478144 356815762928656 282203294255351   delta  1
271234567  form   -234162189321977 266334703524928 131597572463616   delta  2
281234567  form   -64953983507121 435485509110140 17501807131068   delta  25
291234567  form   -32188874491536 421085899135192 131113178295567   delta  3
301234567  form   -291072355399017 231239957531656 120865960338032   delta  2
311234567  form   -59162964411769 373298993398716 231744382168156   delta  1
321234567  form   -178679581561572 333360532348540 116221495145399   delta  3
331234567  form   -76109339460969 419207043002656 60637538834176   delta  7
341234567  form   -142503482378816 157338427610320 297255009808383   delta  1
351234567  form   -38182845947601 439128016327390 8914096464303   delta  49
361234567  form   -181625016690593 131331944117882 243560607302679   delta  1
371234567  form   -93145294060809 381268914088936 131055714230256   delta  3
381234567  form   -226516684127921 436218978493166 4313015428959   delta  101
391234567  form   -128950129919961 245123313648412 260002526172572   delta  1
401234567  form   -134637491397457 225606090025112 266078875334256   delta  1
411234567  form   -160885349613968 431891040617032 11910665055879   delta  36
421234567  form   -77674961374569 373724265120016 175491077521856   delta  2
431234567  form   -18934790450313 435441210621788 60547661144284   delta  7
441234567  form   -190891023045184 90741664881648 243543180160903   delta  1
451234567  form   -251441323061316 71812659791164 187954207967919   delta  1
461234567  form   -273929606532112 178593913031704 148121166323127   delta  2
471234567  form   -377063169236868 436563931671676 2391383506463   delta  183
481234567  form   -52376656915609 432356329570898 34666594431303   delta  12
491234567  form   -404908872154009 398884268755628 21663033069948   delta  19
501234567  form   -23741317830912 419260870807328 193915090907111   delta  2
511234567  form   -126095175334313 381902477690794 95850960231663   delta  4
521234567  form   -205510961807424 434741093279888 6319685796783   delta  69
531234567  form   -175856546727108 117126266077868 256567523594359   delta  1
541234567  form   -94968487660337 324316308513300 234324593444444   delta  1
551234567  form   -138362978954553 238126526556572 248423811414044   delta  1
561234567  form   -92392627005233 302257725411642 278255819144039   delta  1
571234567  form   -124129548476473 423629155445436 29673063040348   delta  14
581234567  form   -50010351316017 437420773312382 14286762697391   delta  30
591234567  form   -219331605782697 111844864876000 207090084628224   delta  1
601234567  form   -25157832366833 394638584860594 382140080575743   delta  1
611234567  form   -321038162819012 214526091037652 115386152206071   delta  2
621234567  form   -40388055848041 378658203237468 314528893913692   delta  1
631234567  form   -121233443693241 300919634945138 213724544892487   delta  1
641234567  form   -211356696191041 49468036723994 226805908932759   delta  1
651234567  form   -84557054742889 363506748706184 183478838180976   delta  2
661234567  form   -83754414452449 281558423213722 343025893263543   delta  1
671234567  form   -196518009372672 208235240166400 191881856332399   delta  1
681234567  form   -12107827461156 434227486813460 116481811572463   delta  3
691234567  form   -35485320380601 416760206546338 144466831857367   delta  2
701234567  form   -277144385228593 436308914120510 3454344265071   delta  126
711234567  form   -116300073184113 264044125290200 267574158604656   delta  1
721234567  form   -298782973318329 390232763093056 35069993409536   delta  11
731234567  form   -65594559685604 326394288849996 334104099631631   delta  1
741234567  form   -84124971192249 407296062861566 84115316142711   delta  5
751234567  form   -124319879196516 256210983824692 258508151733807   delta  1
761234567  form   -29908245409476 403477755583220 262474255272103   delta  1
771234567  form   -55309888843489 404156460943848 139452603929968   delta  3
781234567  form   -307156936521097 188399526585392 129168900751296   delta  2
791234567  form   -245425691002209 170646691289908 168151287554268   delta  1
801234567  form   -2893592082308 438971552299916 129497631372183   delta  3
811234567  form   -111360892857769 426687999223998 27236285599783   delta  15
821234567  form   -34043673913249 417788449343738 144282963237783   delta  2
831234567  form   -334411495718976 350183313814576 53501841783159   delta  7
841234567  form   -297957734276337 230342189457650 118420615184319   delta  2
851234567  form   -108063433198273 323582554334182 207029345852439   delta  1
861234567  form   -379797737373696 438822622282240 1072665148343   delta  409
871234567  form   -284865489112681 329772286677086 74987247681159   delta  5
881234567  form   -249878132541456 123525349161992 179023633747327   delta  1
891234567  form   -130214847116352 367767473302960 113162907106039   delta  3
901234567  form   -197527679869777 337967415571764 101217337079452   delta  3
911234567  form   -154988691853593 336856855010710 130206815863071   delta  2
921234567  form   -128549839576977 279631967402588 225595069196796   delta  1
931234567  form   -20132873456353 420467744490462 216086303983039   delta  1
941234567  form   -214764744790148 178851408731524 188819457733983   delta  1
951234567  form   -89028239580036 428020624038596 30870043205759   delta  14
961234567  form   -128228116649097 432323672368490 14215133763599   delta  30
971234567  form   -50076716588673 401995437921796 162723053358588   delta  2
981234567  form   -300339002085681 228035909431088 118361668010432   delta  2
989484954  new min   form   252159 440675477958146 -137038755464961   delta  -3
991234567  form   -116399206570768 416509917875304 44489919505543   delta  9
1001234567  form   -154045294341753 364721836652102 99277389715759   delta  4
1011234567  form   -133836264066057 177996939220082 303564896581271   delta  1
1021234567  form   -211357796382473 263702843148074 147446284997583   delta  2
1031234567  form   -215616046639812 391580651174500 47375266445119   delta  8
1041234567  form   -92351592346577 353960473183438 186534034456671   delta  2
1051234567  form   -170186585946441 141592900672054 255816765056239   delta  1
1061234567  form   -209575235190633 152185204113688 204025228106224   delta  1
1071234567  form   -301522810224057 205080886815178 126140296617951   delta  2
1081234567  form   -214853799317568 294907429661488 124764473892119   delta  2
1091234567  form   -99548367783044 279325805588292 291747554308223   delta  1
1101234567  form   -309719497730457 232237773096458 113215744235391   delta  2
1111234567  form   -289282371726753 183036034343704 138871828055408   delta  2
1121234567  form   -239195497531456 245255429608496 140099471606679   delta  2

2761234567  form   -192428278034628 88573350422180 242102720699551   delta  1
2767313342  new min   form   8751 440675478108752 -156710092210752   delta  -2
   2991234567  form   -29901906167952 425313755731064 111222727098727   delta  3
3001234567  form   -149844068735713 207745422027814 251989815000183   delta  1
3011234567  form   -404031299066033 399914438004498 21200906567519   delta  19
============================================================================
4551234567  form   -258225803190249 288483139796146 107437322000951   delta  3
4561234567  form   -266358218913033 362413611247306 58991282164143   delta  6
```

Comment: Gee these numbers are causing a stack overflow on your computer.  Perhaps it's safe to say with such large numbers, the continued fraction digit is essentially random and that an exact answer is beyond reach.

Comment: @johnmangual, your conclusion is correct. Not really a stackoverflow, I was not saving anything, but I do need a new computer monitor, it has been getting worse lately. Anyway, beyond reach, probably, but in any case only a few facts might be found, not yet: what is the cycle length? What is the "minimum?" Is the form "ambiguous?" Finally, is $f$ equivalent to $-1 \circ f$ in the class group?